# Setting a cookie for another domain being 302-redirected to

Tags: http, session, cookies, redirect

(This question is more of a reality check than anything else - I'm pretty sure this is possible, but want to be sure.)

I’m writing a proxy server that receives HTTP requests, passes them on to a remote server, and returns the remote server’s response.

I’ve run into a problem where one of the remote server responses is a 302 redirect that sets a cookie. Here’s an example:

```
server: nginx/0.7.65
date: Wed, 26 Jan 2011 04:42:18 GMT
connection: keep-alive
set-cookie: JSESSIONID=FFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUU; Domain=.50.16.34.61; Path=/
location: http://50.16.34.61/client/whatever.html
content-length: "0"
```

When the client follows that redirect to 50.16.34.61 (a different domain than the proxy server) I notice that the cookies haven’t been set.

Am I trying to do something crazy here with the Domain part of the set-cookie directive?

**Edit**

Basically, I’m doing it wrong and according to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt the request-host really needs to be a superset of the Domain in the set-cookie directive.

*/sad-trombone*

Comment: A long time ago that was me, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Domain= cookie stuff will only work if the Host: header that the browser asked for is a superset of the value used.

In your case, it seems like your proxy server is pretending to be another server, so it might make sense to intercept those Location: and Set-Cookie: header lines, among many other things,  and replace the relevant bits to keep pointing at your server.

Answer (score 1):

The client follows the redirect to 50.16.34.61, but was the page requested on that domain? The proxy isn't the problem here—if resource requested (which generated the 302) was on a different domain, you can't set a cookie for a different one.

The proxy certainly shouldn't be getting in the way.

Edit: hold on; is this not actually a HTTP proxy server, but rather a HTTP server that proxies?

Comment: This is an HTTP server that proxies requests. Sorry about the confusing description.

I also feel like a jerk about not being able to mark your answer correct as it totally is, but Metal was a little earlier. Curse you Stack Overflowwwwwwwwww...

Comment: Ahh, I see! Metal was more correct in telling you how to actually solve the problem, though ;-) Changing the Location and Set-Cookie lines are the things to do here. You may also need to do some in-page link changing, which can get ugly ... good luck!